# Python: unpacking string of floats to complex numbers

Tags: python, arrays, struct

I'm fairly new to coding and I'm reading a signal from a binary file. The data is oriented as two 4 byte floats which makes up a complex number, this repeats itself for up to 1500-ish entries

I have been using a for loop to extract the data and append the complex number to an array

```
for x in range(dimX):
    for y in range(dimY):
        complexlist=[]
        #2 floats, each 4 bytes, is one complex number
        trace=stream.readBytes(8*dimZ)
        #Unpack as list of floats
        floatlist=struct.unpack("f"*2*dimZ,trace)
        for i in range(0,len(floatlist)-1,2):
            complexlist.append(complex(floatlist[i],floatlist[i+1]))        
        data[x][y]=np.array(complexlist)
```

where dimX might be in the thousands, DimY is generally <30 and dimZ is <1500

but this is painfully slow in large files

is there a way of reading a buffer of the entire trace and unpack directly to an array of complex numbers?

Comment: You definitely want to start looking at numpy for C speed.  Possibly `numpy.frombuffer', and use one of the complex dtypes from numpy rather than python's complex.  The innermost loop can be unrolled with a comprehension and itertools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can skip the step through python's complex type as, internally, numpy represents an array of `n` complex numbers as a array of `2n` floats.

Here's a simple example from the REPL of how that works:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> a.dtype = complex
>>> a
array([ 1.+2.j,  3.+4.j])
>>>
```

Note though that this doesn't work if the initial array had a `dtype` other than `float`.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> a.dtype = complex
>>> a
array([  4.94065646e-324 +9.88131292e-324j,
         1.48219694e-323 +1.97626258e-323j])
>>>
```

In your case. The dtype you want is `np.dtype('complex64')` since each of your complex numbers is 64 bits(2*4*8).

```
for x in range(dimX):
    for y in range(dimY):
        #2 floats, each 4 bytes, is one complex number
        trace=stream.readBytes(8*dimZ)
        a = np.frombuffer(trace,dtype=np.dtype('complex64'))
        data[x][y] = a
```

That should speed you up quite a bit. Here's an example from the REPL on how `numpy.frombuffer()` works

```
>>> binary_string = struct.pack('2f', 1,2)
>>> binary_string
'\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00@'
>>> numpy.frombuffer(binary_string, dtype=np.dtype('complex64'))
array([ 1.+2.j], dtype=complex64)
>>>
```

Edit: I wasn't aware of the existence of `numpy.frombuffer()`. So I was creating an array of chars and then changing the dtype to obtain the same effect. Thank you @wim

Edit 2:

As for further speed optimisations, you'll probably get a performance boost from using a list comprehension rather than an explicit for loop.

```
for x in range(dimX):
    data[x] = [np.frombuffer(stream.readBytes(8*dimZ), dtype=np.dtype('complex64')) for y in range(dimY)]
```

And yet a level up:

```
data = [[np.frombuffer(stream.readBytes(8*dimZ), dtype=np.dtype('complex64'))
         for y in range(dimY)]
         for x in range(dimX)]
```